# Isomorphism of Forcing Posets

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $\text{Col}(\alpha, \beta)$ be the forcing poset that collapses $\beta$ to $\alpha$, let $Q$ be any old forcing poset, with $|Q| = \lambda$.

Why is $Q \times \text{Col}(\omega, \lambda) \cong \text{Col}(\omega,\lambda)$?

Comment: When you say $\cong$, do you mean as posets or as forcing posets (i.e. that they have the same Boolean completions)?

Comment: The latter (i.e. that if you force with $Q \times \text{Col}(\omega, \lambda)$ you get the same result as forcing with just $\text{Col}(\omega, \lambda)$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence of **Proposition 10.20** in Kanamori's *The Higher Infinite* (p. 129):

> Suppose that $P$ is a separative partial order such that $|P|\leq|\alpha|$ and$$\Vdash_P\exists f(f\colon\omega\to\alpha\text{ is surjective}\land f\notin\check V).$$
>   Then there is an injective, dense embedding of a dense subset of $\text{Col}(\omega,\{\alpha\})$ into $P$.

Note that $\text{Col}(\omega,\lambda)$ has cardinality $\lambda$, and therefore $Q\times\text{Col}(\omega,\lambda)$ has the same cardinality. Both forcings add a new surjection from $\omega$ onto $\lambda$, and therefore both have a dense subset isomorphic to a dense subset of $\text{Col}(\omega,\lambda)$.

It follows that the Boolean completions are isomorphic, and so both forcings are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Asaf for answering all of my set theory questions :).

Comment: No problem @Kris. It's either that or actually working... ;-)